# Не получается сделать говорилку (TTS)

Tags: java, swing

Попытался реализовать говорилку, не работает.
Плохо дружу с Swing.
В общем ошибка здесь такая : после нажатия кнопки должно происходить считывание текста в переменную text вооот.

Вот к чему пришел максимум

```
public class News {

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Parser.parser();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
    frame.setLayout(fl);



    JButton button = new JButton("Test");
    button.setSize(120, 120);
    JTextField tf1;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    tf1 = new JTextField(20);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(tf1); 
    panel.add(button);
    System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C://mbrola");

    VoiceManager vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    Voice voice = vm.getVoice("mbrola_us1");
    String text=null;
    voice.allocate();
    voice.speak(text);
}
```

Comment: http://java-buddy.blogspot.ru/2014/09/google-translater-with-tts-on-javafx.html
вот такое вот увидел,только мне нужно без графической оболочки говорилку...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно делать что-то, когда нажата кнопка, то необходимо повесить лисенер на кнопку и в этом лисенере обрабатывать нужное поведение.

```
button.addActionListener(e - > {
    VoiceManager vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    Voice voice = vm.getVoice("mbrola_us1");
    String text = tf1.getText(); //считываем текст
    voice.allocate();
    voice.speak(text);
});
```

Comment: Почему-то выбрасывает "illegal start of expression"

Comment: Это синтаксическая ошибка. Вы используете какую джаву - 7 или 8?

Comment: У меня 1.8 стоит